# Form Layout issue - Java Swing GUI (Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have this issue with the design of my application when running. The image below shows how I would like my application to look which is created in the design view of netbeans.

[image: Form Editor]

Here is how it looks when the application is running.

[image: GUI when running.]

The border is not even aligned with the text and the button component and scroll-wheel does not match the one in design view. Is there a way that in which i can apply this theme to my running application as the GUI design is hideous.

Comment: Change the font size?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the layout, it's simply that the form designer is showing the system look and feel and you're running with Nimbus. Take a look at [How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more details

In you "main" class/method you will have some code that will likely look like...

```
/* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
/* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
 * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
 */
try {
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
//</editor-fold>
```

Which could simply replace with something like...

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

which will cause Swing to use the system/native look and feel instead

Comment: Does setting the look and feel just adjust the design locally within design view? So is there no way to align the text centre to the border?

Comment: Oh when running it uses the 'Nimbus' LAF. Is this changeable cause locally i am running windows.

Comment: @AcesCharles Yes, it will have some effect on the layout (but that's why you use layout managers), no, there isn't generally away to center the text of the border. *"Oh when running it uses the 'Nimbus' LAF. Is this changeable cause locally i am running windows"* - So you didn't take the time to read [How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) then?

Comment: @AcesCharles Sorry, there is away to get the text centered within the `TitledBorder`, see [`TitledBorder#setTitleJustification`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/TitledBorder.html#setTitleJustification(int))

Comment: Oops, realised I had a portion of my code hidden and did not see this section. Thanks for help and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @AcesCharles No waste, just need to be able to self educate ;)

Comment: for find more look and feels instead default laf , check a lot of possibilities for LaFs as below :

The native for your system
The nimbus LaF
Web LaF
The substance project (forked into the Insubstantial project)
Napkin LaF
Synthetica
Quaqua (looks like aqua from MacOS X)
Seaglass
JGoodies
Liquidlnf
The Alloy Look and Feel
PgsLookAndFeel
JTatoo
Jide look and feel
etc.